# Flash player freezes in fullscreen mode

Tags: flash, performance, fullscreen

A lot of users on one of our online apps complain about the app freezing
in the fullscreen mode.
I googled and came across many others complaining about this problem for
other flash apps.
Is it such a common problem,
or are there known causes for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with GPU acceleration on some video cards.  Have affected users turn off Flash hardware acceleration.

1. Go to any website with Flash (ex., photoshop.com)
2. Right-click on the Flash movie
3. Click Settings...
4. Select the "Display" tab if it's not already selected (first tab)
5. Uncheck "Enable hardware acceleration"

Answer (score 1):

This solved the problem for me. Open a Flash player video. Right click and open `settings`. 
Click the screen icon down on the left side. If the `enable hardware acceleration` is on, disable it.

Answer (score 0):

If you disable "Enable hardware acceleration" and still have this issue:

- go to your video card settings(as for me it is NVidia Control Panel)
- change Integrated graphics to High-Performance processor for FireFox(and anything else you need)
- Apply setting and without any reloads try to view video in fullscreen

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using 
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;